# Joining RDDs from two different databases

Tags: oracle, jdbc, apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to develop a spark application that would get data from two different Oracle databases and work on them.

May be things like joining RDDs that I pulled from two databases to create a new RDD.

Can I create different database connections inside one spark application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try something like this which is `DataFrame` approach though I haven't tested the below.

#### Database 1 :

```
val employees = sqlContext.load("jdbc", 
 Map("url" -> "jdbc:oracle:thin:hr/hr@//localhost:1521/database1", 
"dbtable" -> "hr.employees"))
employees.printschema
```

#### Dabase 2 :

```
val departments  = sqlContext.load("jdbc", 
Map("url" -> "jdbc:oracle:thin:hr/hr@//localhost:1521/database2", 
"dbtable" -> "hr.departments"))
departments.printschema()
```

#### Now join (broadcast is hint that its small data set and can perform broad cast hash join):

```
val empDepartments = employees.join(broadcast(departments), 
        employees("DEPARTMENT_ID")===
        departments("DEPARTMENT_ID"), "inner")
empDepartments.printSchema()

empDepartments.explain(true)
empDepartments.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

RDD ( or now dataframe) is an abstraction layer where all data appear to be of similar format irrespective of the underneath datasource.

So once you load your data into a dataframe, you should be able to use it just as is.

```
sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load("somepath").registerTempTable("avro_data")

sqlContext.read.format("parquet").load("someotjerpath").registerTempTable("parquet_data")

sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.redshift").option("url", jdbcConnectionString).option("query", query).load.registerTempTable("redshift_data")`
```

and then be able to do:

```
sqlContext.sql("select * from avro_data a left join parquet_data p on a.key = b.key left join redshift_data r on r.key=a.key")
```